# Mysqli does not retrieve my data

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to get  data from my query but it does not work. My database is "app", that contains a table called "people". "people" has 5 column "id"., "first_name", "last_name", "bio", "created"  i don't get any data retrieved!!

```php
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '****');

if ($db->connect_errno) {
    die('Sorry we are having some problem! ');
}

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM people");

print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: When you get this working, you still won't receive row data back in `$result`. You must first fetch from it via `$result->fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: "Does not work" is _not_ an error description that helps. What _does_ happen? Do you get an error message? Which? Does nothing happen at all? Does the universe implode?

Comment: Simply calling `print_r($result);` will return _something_ but probably not what you want. It will provide metadata about the rowset as present in the `mysqli_result` object.

Comment: You need to add some error reporting to your script and you will then be able to tell us why "it's not working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to select the database:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '****', 'app');
```

or alternative:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '****');
$db->select_db('app');
```

also you need to fetch the data once you get the result:

```
$data = array();
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM people");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $data[]= $row;
}

print_r($data);
```

Comment: He also forgot to call `$result->fetch_assoc()` (or one of the other `fetch` methods).

Comment: You right I just noticed it , will point out in my edit

Comment: Thank for the answer so now I'm getting the following:  Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::db_fetch_assoc()

Comment: Ok it works i had typo db_fetch_assoc :)